# Reference functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, reference

I have a function that gives me the error "cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &'" when I try to compile it.

```
int& preinc(int& x) { 
    return x++;
}
```

If I replace x++ with x, it will compile, but I'm not sure how that makes it any different. I thought that x++ returns x before it increments x, so shouldn't "return x++" be the same as "return x" with regard to what preinc returns? If the problem is with the ++ operator acting on x, then why won't it generate any error if I put the line "x++" before or after the return statement, or replace x++ with ++x?

Comment: I'd call this "postinc" rather than "preinc"....

Comment: Thank you everyone who answered the question. I didn't realize x++ made a temporary copy. Makes sense now.

Comment: you are expected to accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x++` creates a temporary copy of the original, increments the original, and then returns the temporary.

Because your function returns a reference, you are trying to return a reference to the temporary copy, which is local to the function and therefore not valid.

Answer (score 11):

Your function does two things:

- Increments the `x` that you pass in by reference
- Returns a reference to the *local* result of the expression `x++`

The reference to a local is invalid, and returning anything at all from this function seems completely redundant.

The following is fixed, but I still think there's a better approach:

```
int preinc(int& x) {
   return x++; // return by value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `x++` returns x before it is incremented. Therefore it has to return a copy, the copy is a temporary and you can only pass temporaries as constant references.

`++x` on the other hand returns the original `x` (although incremented), therefore it will work with your function.